# Working with Lightbox Jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

I have designed a web page where  on the left there is a div element and in the center there is iframe and on the right I have another iframe.

1.In the center iframe I load thumbnail images on clicking those images the lightbox plugin is get called and larger images has to be displayed on entire document(with blurred background).

2.Problem I'm facing is that the lightbox plug-in is loading inside the center iframe rather than in the entire document(as in many of social networking sites).

3.I have downloaded lightbox plugin from internet and using it in my webpage

4.I want the image to be displayed in entire document with the help of lightbox .

Any help is greatly appreciated

here is the code snippet which I have written

```
<!--this code is written in home page-->
<div>
<ul>
        <li><a href="http://localhost/php/image.php?category=sea" target="description" class="underline">SEA</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost/php/image.php?category=ANIMALS" target="description" class="underline">ANIMALS &amp; BIRDS</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost/php/image.php?category=plants" target="description" class="underline">plants</a></li>
     <li><a href="http://localhost/php/image.php?category=Tourism" target="description" class="underline">Tourism</a></li>
<ul>
</div> 
<filedset><iframe name="description" width="725px" height="800px" align="left" frameborder="0" id="description"></iframe></fieldset>
<fieldset>
<iframe name="info" width="300px" height="380px" frameborder="0" src="UserInformation.php" id="iframeid"><!--logged in user's information-->
</iframe>
</fieldset>
<!--this code is written in image.php file-->
<head>
//calling JQUERY LIGHT BOX PLUGIN HERE ON clicking an image displayed in this page(within iframe name="description")
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/jquery.lightbox-0.5.css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#gallery a').lightBox();
    });
    </script>
</head>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give us an example of what you're currently doing?

http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: A page is divide into 3 sections vertically.First section has menu item on clicking on menu item ,list of images are loaded from database using php on the same page but within iframe.when thubnail image is clicked lightbox plugin is get called to display bigger image.Problem is lightbox is loaded within the iframe I want it to be dispalyed in foreground and all other 3 sections of the page in background(as in Social networking sites).

Comment: What I meant to say, is we actually need to see your code.

Comment: I have edited my question by including the code,please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the solution for the problem which I was facing, here

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-19051.html